# Remover itens de uma lista que estão em outra

Tags: python, lista

Eu tenho duas listas com valores, e quando tento pesquisar um item de uma em outra, para ver se existe, está retornando `False` mesmo se sabendo que o item existe na lista pesquisada.

```
proc = [1,2,3,4]
fat = [3,4,5,6]


for p in proc:
  if proc[0] not in fat:
    result.append(proc[0])

print(result)

[]
```

Estas listas estao vindo de `SELECT` em um banco de dados, e contém um campo de tabelas.

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas **se** vc quer os elementos de `proc` que não estão em `fat`, basta fazer `result = [ p for p in proc if p not in fat ]`. E se a ordem dos elementos não for importante, outra alternativa é `result = list(set(proc) - set(fat))` (já que um `set` é otimizado para não permitir duplicados, mas ele não garante a mesma ordem da lista original)

Comment: é isso mesmo, python, funcionou perfeitamente. eu estou acostumado a usar for pra percorrer a lista, não percebo que o python é perfeito nisso de manipular listas tuplas e dicionários.

Comment: veja se atende, rodei no ideone dessa forma https://ideone.com/0tMlhG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia (confirmada nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/463500/pesquisa-de-um-item-em-uma-lista#comment878382_463500)) é ter os elementos de `proc` que **não** estão em `fat`, então uma opção é:

```
proc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fat = [3, 4, 5, 6]

result = []
for p in proc:
  if p not in fat:
    result.append(p)

print(result) # [1, 2]
```

Ou seja, para cada elemento de `proc`, verifique se ele não está em `fat` (e se não estiver, adicione em `result`).

O erro do seu código é que você estava verificando `proc[0]` (o primeiro elemento de `proc`) em todas as iterações.

---

Outra alternativa para o código acima é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
result = [ p for p in proc if p not in fat ]
```

---

Mas tem um detalhe aí. Para cada elemento de `proc`, temos que verificar se o mesmo está em `fat`. E [o operador `in` tem complexidade linear](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list): ele percorre `fat` desde o início, até encontrar o elemento (ou percorre a lista toda, no caso do elemento não existir nela). Ou seja, este algoritmo percorre várias e várias vezes a mesma lista (o que o torna um forte candidato a ser um [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)).

**Se a ordem dos elementos não é importante, e não há elementos duplicados** (ou há, mas no resultado as duplicadas podem ser eliminadas), uma opção é usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set), que é uma [estrutura otimizada](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) para certas operações, como verificar se um elemento existe, entre outras.

Assim, a ideia é transformar cada lista em um `set`, subtraí-los (assim eu terei outro `set` contendo os elementos de um que não estão no outro), e no final transformo novamente em lista:

```
result = list(set(proc) - set(fat))
```

Lembrando novamente que:

- um `set` **não** garante a ordem dos elementos, então a lista `result` não necessariamente terá os números na mesma ordem em que estavam na lista original (pode ser que sim, pode ser que não, então não conte com isso)
- um `set` elimina valores duplicados, então se a lista `proc` for, por exemplo, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]`, o resultado final será apenas `[1, 2]`

Mas se manter a ordem original dos elementos e/ou não eliminar valores duplicados forem requisitos do problema, aí não tem jeito, tem que fazer o `for` mesmo.

---

Apenas para comparar o desempenho de cada solução, fiz um pequeno teste com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
import random
import timeit

# criar listas com mil números aleatórios
nums = range(10000) # números possíveis para as listas
proc = random.choices(nums, k=1000)
fat = random.choices(nums, k=1000)

n = 100 # rodar 100 vezes cada teste
r = 3 # repetir por 3 vezes (assim, repeat retorna uma lista com 3 tempos)
print(timeit.repeat("result = []\nfor p in proc:\n  if p not in fat:\n    result.append(p)", repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('[ p for p in proc if p not in fat ]', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.repeat('list(set(proc) - set(fat))', repeat=r, number=n, globals=globals()))
```

Claro que os tempos podem variar conforme o *hardware* e outro fatores, e para listas pequenas - como as que você usou - a diferença será insignificante, mas no geral, usar `set` se mostrou bem mais rápido. Na minha máquina os tempos foram (em segundos):

```
[1.4215344, 1.4107937, 1.4132282999999997]
[1.4147277999999996, 1.4120507999999994, 1.3960000999999993]
[0.015077500000000299, 0.014714099999999064, 0.015252100000001434]
```

Ou seja, usar `set` foi, em geral, cerca de 100 vezes mais rápido. No [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/FreeTreasuredBits#main.py) os resultados foram similares.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi do seu enunciado, você está precisando encontrar os valores que são `comuns` às duas listas.

Se o que importar for o `valor` do elemento, sem levar em consideração a `quantidade` de ocorrências de cada elemento, podemos converter as duas listas para `conjuntos`, calcular a intersecção dos conjuntos e, em seguida, exibir o resultado em uma nova lista. Para isso podemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
proc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fat = [3, 4, 5, 6]
proc = set(proc)
fat = set(fat)

inter = list(proc & fat)
print(inter)
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/lkfcdgof-solkarped).

Agora, se você pretendo exibir os elementos em ordem crescente de valores, você pode ordenar os valores na saída. Para isso aplicamos a função `sorted`. Para isso basta utilizar o algoritmo...

```
proc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fat = [3, 4, 5, 6]
proc = set(proc)
fat = set(fat)

inter = list(sorted(proc & fat))
print(inter)
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/urprehnt-solkarped).